# How do I quote a line from a comic book?

Tags: non-fiction, quotes, comics

I am writing a book report and part of it says *'Copy a line or short part from your book you found interesting AND explain why you chose it. Use quotation marks around the part you chose.'* My problem is that I am using a comic book. I have gotten two different confusing responses and a lot of ways to cite it. I don't need the part that goes in the (parenthesis) but how it would look when I put it into "quotation marks". Please give an example.

I am quoting the non-fiction graphic novel Santiago!: Santiago Ramón y Cajal! Artist, Scientist, Troublemaker

[image: Picture of the book's cover]

Comment: What do you mean by not needing the part in parenthesis?

Comment: I mean that I'm not talking about adding the author's last name and the page number. I know how to do that, I need the part in the quotation marks.

Comment: I'd literally just take the text from the speech bubble you want to refer to and put it quotations. So if character A said "I'll be back,"  just put it in quotations like I did. Maybe refer to page and panel number if you need to cite it specificially.

Comment: Can you post an example of something you might want to quote? It's not clear what the problem is. Is the issue that you want to quote text from multiple boxes/bubbles and don't know how to group it?

Answer (score 2):

In scholarly works, comics are cited as *figures*. That is, you place the panel(s) or comic page on its own line between paragraphs of text and give it a caption that describes it and gives its source. In text, you refer to the figure by its number.

Example (note the reference to the figure in the bottom half of the preceding page):

[image: page 620]

[image: page 621]

What format your captions should have will depend on your style guide.